# How to show two items of a list and collapse the others?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have  a list that's generated from backend :

```
<ul>
{% for element in  elements %}
  <li>{{element }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to show only the two first items and collapse the others (maybe with a link 'see all' when clicked it shows me the rest of items)

is this possible ?

Comment: Here a nice and easy to use readmore plugin : http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/
Hope this help :)

Comment: Do not use an extra plugin for this, just make a counter to count the loop steps and for 1 and 2 show them, otherwise collapse them

Comment: Yes, it's possible - what have you tried so far?  You can do this with js and a css class to hide all but the first two.

Comment: anything is possible..show us your code first. fiddle will be better

Comment: this is a link to a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9q8adcty/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
var limit = 1;

     $(".list-group-item").each(function(i) {
        if (i <= limit) {
          $(this).addClass('show');
        }else{
         $(this).addClass('add-more');
        }
        $(this).not('.show').hide();
      });

})

  $('.see-emails').click(function() {
   $('.add-more').show();
    $('a').hide();
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="collapseListGroup1">
  <ul class="list-group">

    <li class="list-group-item"> email1 </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> email2 </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> email3 </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> email4 </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> email 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a class="collapsed see-emails" >
          See Emails
        </a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but  I want to show the link`see emails` with the two first emails and when I click on `see emails` it shows me the rest of mails (maybe changing the link's label to `see more ` is more significant

Comment: ok ive edited the snippet above. Please check once,and there is more to be done.

Comment: Hi this is useful for me. However, what is the css for the .show and .add-more classes?

Comment: Actually, how could I modify this to use with the bootstrap collapse function, without adding extra js classes?